# A case where Schwarz Theorem can't be used.

Tags: real-analysis, multivalued-functions

Given the function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,

$f(x,y) = \frac{xy(x²-y²)}{x²+y²}, $ if $ (x,y) \neq (0,0)$

$f(x,y) = 0,  $ if $  (x,y) = (0,0)$

Why isn't valid $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} f(0,0) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y \partial x} f(0,0) $ ? 
Isn't $f$ 2 times differentiable, since I can calculate all the four 2-order partial derivatives of $f$ and since all the limits of them are $0$ and $f(0,0)=0$? Probably I'm not properly evaluating the limits. I believe $f$ can't be 2-times differentiable, since Schawrz Theorem is "failing" for $f$.

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Existence of second order partial derivatives is not sufficient for the function to be twice differentiable : they all must be continuous.

Comment: Can I say $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y \partial x} f$ isn't continuous at $(0,0)$ since 
$\lim_{(x,0) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y \partial x} f(x,y) = 1 \neq -1 =  \lim_{(0,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y \partial x} f(x,y) \Rightarrow \nexists \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y \partial x} f(x,y) $ ?

Comment: Well, I did not compute your derivatives, but if what you've written is correct, then it indeed shows that the partial derivatives are not continuous at the origin.